# deleting strings from cell, keeping number in that cell

Tags: excel, string

So I have an imported report from word that keeps the units on the numbers. I could use find/replace but I need to import similar reports often and would like to delete all instances of the units while keeping the numbers in the cell. The units being imported are 200 sq.ft. and 100 in. The numbers change everytime but the units including the space between the unit is the same.

```
Sub DeleteChar()
Dim lastrow as integer
Dim myCell as Range
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row    
    For y= 3 to 10
        For x = lastrow to 2 step -10
            If Right(Len(myCell.Value),7) = " sq.ft." then
            myCell.Value = Left(myCell.Value, len(myCell.Value-7))
            end if
        Next x
    Next y
End Sub
```

Needs work. Attempted to set it to find instances of the first 7 characters at the right to be " sq.ft." Then replace that cell with the same value - those 7 characters at end.

Comment: Is there a question here?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get run time error 91, related to object variables

Answer (score 1):

If you numbers are always left of the text, use val:

So instead of your If:

```
        If Right(Len(myCell.Value),7) = " sq.ft." then
        myCell.Value = Left(myCell.Value, len(myCell.Value-7))
        end if
```

Use

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(x,y).value = Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(x,y).value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteChar()
Dim i, lastrow As Integer
Dim myCell As Range
Dim arr() As String
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    arr = Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, " ")
    Cells(i, 2).Value = cDbl(arr())
Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if your data input is inconsistent with the delimiters, this code looks for a space character, so I'd have to add a handle if sometimes a record doesn't include the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you, I get a run time error '9'. Subscript out of range. Then I adjusted it a little to fit only the columns D, G, and J (where all instances will show up) and it works well for column D, still shows that run time error related to line Cells(i, 4).Value = arr(0). Does not run for G and J after.

Comment: If I change argument of arr(0) to arr(), it will delete all units for the necessary columns but considers them to be text rather than numbers. I fixed this issue with the following script, it now has the following which converts, thanks again, works fine now.                                                                   
        [D:D].Select
 With Selection
  .NumberFormat = "General"
  .Value = .Value
 End With

Comment: It does that because arr() is defined as a string, wrap it it a cDbl operator to convert it to a double (numeric value). I edited my answer accordingly, let me know if it works for you.